# Alternative key label for android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, label, key

I'm creating my own keyboard, but have trouble to display an alternative label on the keys. So besides the normal label (Q,W,E,R,T,Y) I would like to display a label specifying the character added when the key is longpressed (0,1,2,3,...). Not in a popup, but on the key (like the default android keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

You may draw your keyboard from scratch ([Android Source](http://android.googlesource.com/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/inputmethodservice;h=f116e3106d62cc9da9e05553e927878f378a606b;hb=HEAD))

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    onBufferDraw();
    if (mBuffer!=null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBuffer, 0, 0, null);
}
```